# Heroku wrongly detecting my Node app as a Ruby app

Tags: ruby, node.js, heroku

I have a Node project that is using Bundler and Guard to handle my pre-compilations steps.
This means that I have a Gemfile in the root of my project along with the package.json file.

My problem is that Heroku believes that my project is a Ruby app, just because the Gemfile exists. And complains that I have not committed the Gemfile.lock, which I don't want to commit.

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby app detected
 !
 !     Gemfile.lock is required. Please run "bundle install" locally
 !     and commit your Gemfile.lock.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Is there a way to tell Heroku that the app is a Node app and not a Ruby app?

Comment: I think you should ask the heroku support.

Comment: I suppose, I should have done that directly. I thought I would get a faster answer here, though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there's a new way to do this as `BUILDPACK_URL` is now deprecated, explained [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application), but essentially the command is:

`$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`

You may also specify a buildpack during app creation:

`$ heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/nodejs`

Answer (score 34):

The solution to this, with a lot of help from Heroku Support is: **use a build pack!**

Override the Heroku default buildpacks by specifying a custom buildpack in the `BUILDPACK_URL` config var

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
```

You can also specify a buildpack during app creation

```
$ heroku create -s cedar --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
```

Simple when you know it. Some more documentation can be found [at Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)

Comment: At the Heroku Dev Center link that andersjanmyr noted, they have the buildpacks in a certain order in a table, and they say: "By default, these buildpacks will be searched in this order until a match is detected and used to compile your app."