# Heroku won't run node.

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I have a sails js app I am trying launch on a heroku server. From what I can tell, the heroku app is installing ruby and not node by default.

I have a bower.json file, a package.json file and a Procfile.

ERROR:

```
Starting process with command `node app.js`
bash: node: command not found
```

Procfile:

```
web: node app.js
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "node": "*",
    "sails": "~0.10.5",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.0",
    "request": "^2.51.0",
    "node-fullbox-api": "*",
    "stripe": "*",
    "rc": "~0.5.0",
    "bower": "^1.3.9",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-banner": "^0.2.3",
    "grunt-bower": "^0.14.0",
    "grunt-bowercopy": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-config-dir": "^0.3.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-githooks": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-jscs": "^0.6.2",
    "grunt-lodash": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-modernizr": "^0.5.2",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-scss-lint": "^0.3.3",
    "grunt-string-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-stripmq": "0.0.6",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^0.4.0",
    "jquery-builder": "^0.7.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.4.0",
    "lodash": "^1.3.1",
    "lodash-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "rjs-build-analysis": "0.0.3",
    "time-grunt": "^0.3.2",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
    "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
    "include-all": "~0.1.3",
    "underscore": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node npm-postinstall.js"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node app.js",
      "debug": "node debug app.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.0",
    "shortid": "^2.1.3",
    "node": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
      "node": "*",
      "npm":  "*",
      "ruby": "*"
  }
}
```

As for testing: I can run heroku local and if fires up a server just fine. npm start and npm install work just fine. node app.js starts the app just fine.

What I have found is that when I connect to heroku via: `heroku run bash`

I get a command line that I can run these:

```
~ $ which ruby
/app/bin/ruby
~ $ npm install
bash: npm: command not found
~ $ bower install
bash: bower: command not found
~ $ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

What am I doing wrong?! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Okay I found my answer. Every time I pushed new code it would say:

```
remote: -----> Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:        Detected buildpacks: Ruby, Node.js
remote:        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
```

Paired with it saying that `node command not found`, I was able to track down that heroku has a default order in which it detects server types for an install. In this case it was ruby.

I found the answer here:
[Heroku wrongly detecting my Node app as a Ruby app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008200/heroku-wrongly-detecting-my-node-app-as-a-ruby-app)

Which was to do this:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
$ git commit -am "empty" --allow-empty
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: Good find - also the BUILDPACK_URL config is being deprecated in favor of a plugin specifically for managing buildpacks (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack) so you may want to use `buildpacks:set` instead.

Comment: `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`