# Using Heroku for a Node web application

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-applications

I am trying to set up a project on Heroku. I went through their [tutorial for Node apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) and I am now trying to use my repository to work on my web app. I have already created the project and it shows up on my Heroku dashboard but I can't push anything to it. This is the message I get every time:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/nodejs
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/nodejs
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to your_web_app.
```

I've made sure the buildpack is set to nodejs. I used information from Heroku along with [Heroku wrongly detecting my Node app as a Ruby app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008200/heroku-wrongly-detecting-my-node-app-as-a-ruby-app), but still I cannot deploy.

I also already went into the package.json file and added in my node version under the "engine" section. Why can't I deploy to Heroku still?

EDIT: Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your package.json?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon I just posted it. Sorry for the late response

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon my procfile only has one line:

`web: node index.js`
I got this from going through the tutorial on heroku

Comment: i got it, it seems you made some changes in your app like added package.json later or something else that caused heroku buildpack confusion,
`heroku buildpacks:clear` //will clear buildpack
`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs` //will set correct buildpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure following things:

1- app has a `package.json` file in the root directory.

2- app has node version defined in `package.json` as:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "4.1.1"
  },
```

Edit: **buildpacks fix**,

`heroku buildpacks:clear` //clear buildpack

`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs` //set correct build pack for node.js app

**OR**

`heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs -a your-app-name`

Comment: Zeeshan, I do have a package.json file in the root directory and I just posted the contents in my original question. Why should I set node as version 4.1.1? When I run `node --version` I get v5.7.0 so that's why I have that instead of 4.1.1

Comment: please try updated answer and let me know if it works for you

Comment: This worked! I also have a couple things wrong with my git remote names but I got those worked out separately. These commands correctly set my buildpack.