# Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected in mean app

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, mean

trying to deploy my mean app to Heroku

getting this error

> Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
>   remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
>   remote:       to use for this application automatically.
>   remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
>   remote: 
>   remote: Verifying deploy....
>   remote: 
>   remote: !   Push rejected to

The following is my package.json file. Please check it......

```
{
  "name": "genealogy",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "morgan": "~1.5.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "method-override": "~2.3.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "express-session": "~1.11.2",
    "errorhandler": "~1.3.6",
    "compression": "~1.4.4",
    "lodash": "~3.9.3",
    "ejs": "~2.3.1",
    "mongoose": "~4.0.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.0.1",
    "express-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "passport": "~0.2.2",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-facebook": "latest",
    "passport-twitter": "latest",
    "passport-google-oauth": "latest",
    "composable-middleware": "^0.3.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^0.8.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.3.5",
    "socketio-jwt": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.7.2",
    "grunt-wiredep": "~1.8.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-newer": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.2.3",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.1.1",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.1.5",
    "grunt-nodemon": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.4",
    "grunt-dom-munger": "^3.4.0",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-injector": "~0.5.4",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.2",
    "grunt-build-control": "DaftMonk/grunt-build-control",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.10.2",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.5.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.3.1",
    "grunt-express-server": "~0.4.17",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.3",
    "open": "~0.0.4",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.5",
    "connect-livereload": "~0.4.0",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-ng-jade2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.11",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-jade-preprocessor": "0.0.11",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma": "~0.12.9",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "supertest": "~0.11.0",
    "should": "~3.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/app.js",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "update-webdriver": "node node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: do you have proper `package.json` at root of your app?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon i am added my package.json file

Comment: okay I see that, yesterday I answered same questions, it worked for him, try it if works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816242/using-heroku-for-a-node-web-application/35816738#35816738

Comment: or let me know if problem is still there

Comment: did it work for you?